# Max Consecutive Ones

Tags: python, algorithm

I am practicing two pointers techniques  to solve [Max Consecutive Ones - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones/)

> Given a binary array, find the maximum number of consecutive 1s in this array.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [1,1,0,1,1,1]
> Output: 3
> Explanation: The first two digits or the last three digits are consecutive 1s.
>  The maximum number of consecutive 1s is 3.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> - The input array will only contain `0` and `1`.
> - The length of input array is a positive integer and will not exceed 10,000

The solution use Kadane algorithms

```
class Solution:
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: "List[int]") -> int:

        loc_max = glo_max = 0
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] == 1: 
                loc_max += 1
            elif nums[i] != 1:
                glo_max = max(glo_max, loc_max)
                loc_max = 0  
        #in case of the corner case [.....,1 ,1, 1]         
        return max(glo_max, loc_max)
```

The problem with the solution is that it's not a decent two pointers solution with slow and fast pointer.(It did not an explicit slow pointer)

A intuitive idea to employ slow pointer is to take a slow pointer to remember the starting index of consecutive ones,  when fast pointer reach a non-one, the relation is `length= fast - slow`.

However, it is difficult to locate slow pointing to a first One. `[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`,

As a comprised proposal, re-define slow to the forward non-One of a ones array,when fast reach to another non-One. Use relation: length = fast -slow + 1

```
class Solution:
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: "List[int]") -> int:
        """
        #1Sort####
        ##2Strategy######
        CP: two pointers
        RU: res  = fast - slow 
        """
       ###3Solve######
        slow, fast, glo_max = 0, 0, 0
        for fast in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[fast] != 1: #stop
                loc_max = fast -slow + 1
                glo_max = max(glo_max, loc_max)
                slow = fast 
        return max(loc_max, glo_max)
        ####4Check#########################
        #[0, 0,1, 0, 1, 1]
```

I tried and debugged multiple times to define slow as the first index of Ones sub-array,  did not get the desired result.

Could you please give any hints for that solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are pretty close, it's just a matter of really watching when the indexes get updated relative you where you calculate the length. And there are some tricky cases like `[1]` that will fail if it's not correct.

I find it easier to do this with a while loop so I can be explicit about where the indexes are updated. Here's one way that works:

```
 def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(nums):
        slow, fast, glo_max, loc_max = 0, 0, 0, 0
        while fast < len(nums):
            if nums[fast] == 0:
                loc_max = fast - slow  
                glo_max = max(glo_max, loc_max)
                slow = fast + 1      # need to add one more because we haven't incremented fast yet

            fast += 1
        loc_max = fast - slow        # end check for cases that end with 1
        return max(loc_max, glo_max)

findMaxConsecutiveOnes([1])    # 1 
findMaxConsecutiveOnes([1, 1]) # 2
findMaxConsecutiveOnes([0, 1]) # 1
findMaxConsecutiveOnes([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]) # 3
```

This passes the leet code test, but doesn't set any speed records.

Answer (score 1):

u can try the below solution.
Basically u keep a track of count until u hit 0 and then return the maxCount.

```
  public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    int currentCount=0;
    int maxCount = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]==1){
            currentCount++;
            if(currentCount>maxCount){
                maxCount=currentCount;
            }
        }
        else{
            currentCount=0;
        }

    }
    return maxCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this program like below (1 line solution) :

```
class Solution:
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        return len(max("".join(map(str, nums)).split("0")))
```

[image]

May this solution help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this:

```
class Solution:
    def findMaxConsecutiveOnes(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        c = 0
        r = 0
        for i,v in enumerate(nums):
            if v == 0:
                c = 0
            else:
                c +=1
                r = max(r,c)
        return r
```

Here is my time and space analysis results:
[image]